# Undefined control sequence \bbl@nonfrenchlistspacing

Tags: document-classes

I am trying to run the sample file `hsp-monograph.ltx` that comes with `ouvrage-hermes` downloaded from http://www.iste.co.uk/

```
\documentclass[english,allpages]{ouvrage-hermes}[2005/11/14]

% Preamble: Package loading (optional)
% \usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

% Preamble: User commands and environments (optional)
% \newcommand{\diff}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{d}#1}}

% Preamble: Title, author, and date (mandatory)
\title[%
Short Title]{%
Complete Title}

\author{%
John \Name{Smith}\\ Paul \Name{Jones}}

\date{%
\today{}}

% Preamble: Regenerate the index (mandatory)
\makeindex

% Document body: Beginning (mandatory)
\begin{document}

% Document body: Front matter (mandatory)
\frontmatter

% Front matter: Title page (mandatory)
\maketitle

% Front matter: Table of contents (mandatory)
\tableofcontents

% Front matter: Foreword (optional)
% \include{foreword}
% Here is the typical contents of this included file:
%%%% \chapter{Foreword}
%%%%
%%%% [text]
%%%%
%%%% \vspace{11pt}
%%%%
%%%% \begin{flushright}
%%%%  John \Name{Smith}\\
%%%%  Paul \Name{Jones}
%%%% \end{flushright}

% Front matter: Introduction (optional)
% \include{introduction}
% Here is the typical contents of this included file:
%%%% \chapter{Introduction}
%%%%
%%%% [text]

% Document body: Main matter (mandatory)
\mainmatter

% Main matter: First regular chapter (mandatory)
\include{chapter_1}
% Here is the typical contents of this included file:
%%%% \chapter[%
%%%% Short Title]{%
%%%% Complete Title}
%%%%
%%%% [text]

% Main matter: First appendix (optional)
% \include{appendix_1}
% Here is the typical contents of this included file:
%%%% \cleardoublepage
%%%% \appendix
%%%% \chapter[%
%%%% Short Title]{%
%%%% Complete Title}
%%%%
%%%% [text]

% Document body: Back matter (mandatory)
\backmatter

% Back matter: Bibliography chapter (mandatory)
\bibliography{database}

% Back matter: Index chapter (mandatory)
\printindex

% Document body: End (mandatory)
\end{document}
```

But I am getting the following error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@mkhermes ->\bbl@nonfrenchlistspacing 
                                       \gdef \itemize {\hermesitemize }\gdef...
l.24 \begin{document}
```

Can anyone help me sort this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The command `\bbl@nonfrenchlistspacing` has disappeared from `babel-french` some time between 2007 and 2008.

The only reasonable thing to do is to add

```
\makeatletter
\let\bbl@nonfrenchlistspacing\relax
\makeatother
```

before `\begin{document}` and tell the maintainers of the class that they should update it.